# Update and Insert Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to create a stored procedure that performs insert or update operation on a column if
that column does not contains a value that already exists in database it should allow insert when  COUNT(field) = 0 or update when COUNT(field)=0 or 1 And I should know that either of these operation is performed or not.
Please solve my problem using COUNT not Exists because that won't work for UPDATE.

I am working in ASP.net - I have two columns of a table that are needed to be kept unique without using the unique constraint. So I want a procedure like this:

```
create proc usp_checkall @field1 varchar(20), 
                         @field2 varchar(20), 
                         @ID int, 
                         @count int output
```

Now your query on updating/inserting @field1 & @field2 on basis of @id

Comment: And what have you already tried?

Comment: Yes I am talking about SQL server

Comment: Exists is better than Count

Comment: Exists wont work for update. Coz it will allow user to enter data in table that is already present

Answer (score 8):

If you happen to have SQL Server 2008, you could also try:

```
MERGE dbo.SomeTable AS target
    USING (SELECT @ID, @Field_1, @Field_2) AS source (ID, Field_1, Field_2)
        ON (target.ID = source.ID)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET Field_1 = source.Field_1, Field_2 = source.Field_2
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
        INSERT (ID, Field_1, Field_2)
        VALUES (source.ID, source.Field_1, source.Field_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
INSERT INTO your_table
  (column)
VALUES
  ([ your_value ])
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                   FROM your_table 
                  WHERE t.column = [ your_value ])
```

That will work on SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, Postgres.  All that's needed is to use the db appropriate variable reference.  IE: For MySQL & SQL Server:

```
INSERT INTO your_table
  (column)
VALUES
  ( @your_value )
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                   FROM your_table 
                  WHERE t.column = @your_value)
```

To see if anything was inserted, get the value based on @@ROWCOUNT if using SQL Server. Use SQL%ROWCOUNT if you are using Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

```
if Exists select * from Yourtable WHere Your Criteria
begin
  update ...
end
else
begin
  insert ...
end
```

Comment: Will the EXISTS lock the PK being queried such that there is no possbility of another user doing an INSERT in the meantime? If not then there is the posibility that the EXISTS finds NO row, but the subsequent INSERT fails because the row has already been inserted (by then).  I don't know the answer WRT the Isolation level, hence my question.

Comment: Exists will also not work for update. Suppose if user updates a record and enters a value that already exists in database then exists will allow user perform update operation that is not correct

Answer (score 0):

This kind of approach will do the trick. @AlreadyExisted could be an OUTPUT parameter on the sproc for your calling code to check once it's returned.

```
DECLARE @AlreadyExisted BIT
SET @AlreadyExisted = 0

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE YourField = @FieldValue)
    BEGIN
        -- Record already exists
        SET @AlreadyExisted = 1

        UPDATE YourTable
        SET....
        WHERE YourField = @FieldValue
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        -- Record does not already exist
        INSERT YourTable (YourField,....) VALUES (@FieldValue,.....)
    END
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. But being a beginner still i am not able make your reply work for me.

Comment: Let me explain you the exact scenario. I am working in ASP.net I have tw0 columns of a table that are needed to be kept unique without using the unique constraint. So I want a procedure like this.. create proc usp_checkall @field1 varchar(20),@field2 varchar(20),@ID int,@cunt int output Now your query on updating/inserting @field1,@field2 on basis of @id

Comment: I think you need to add more detail to your original question.  Impossible to decipher from an unformatted comment.